# What is difference between different ways in creating an array in java?

Tags: java

Could someone tell me the difference between the following two statements "under the hood"?

```
int [] input = new int[] {1,2,3};

int [] input = {1,2,3};
```

Comment: why do you think there is a difference and why do you care?

Comment: You can make a quick test, compile, and using `javap -c` to disassemble it, see that these two statements result in the same instructions. When I tried they were the exact same 16 instructions. There is no difference after compilation, but human-wise one or the other may be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

To Java, there is absolutely no difference between the two.

In both you allocate three slots in memory and save "1, 2, 3" continuously in those memory slots.

`[1]--[2]--[3]`

Humanly-wise, the most common way to write it is `int [] input = {1,2,3}`

If you simply want to allocate an array and don't want to put any values in it you can even use `int [] input = new int[3]` which will allocate three spaces in memory with 0s instead for you to use later and then simply add the values afterwards. All three ways are the same to Java as an array is an array to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

No difference. They both compile to the same code.

Decompiler output created using `javap -c Test.class`.

```java
int [] input = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

```
 0: iconst_3               // x = new int[3]
 1: newarray       int
 3: dup                    // x[0] = 1
 4: iconst_0
 5: iconst_1
 6: iastore
 7: dup                    // x[1] = 2
 8: iconst_1
 9: iconst_2
10: iastore
11: dup                    // x[2] = 3
12: iconst_2
13: iconst_3
14: iastore
15: astore_1               // int [] input = x
```

<sup>*In the above comments, `x` represents the top value of the expression stack.*</sup>

```java
int [] input = {1,2,3};
```

```
 0: iconst_3
 1: newarray       int
 3: dup
 4: iconst_0
 5: iconst_1
 6: iastore
 7: dup
 8: iconst_1
 9: iconst_2
10: iastore
11: dup
12: iconst_2
13: iconst_3
14: iastore
15: astore_1
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between the two ways.

Comment: @Reimeus Nope, this is a valid SO answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365206/no-option-for-already-commented-on-for-low-quality-posts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer